# Meaning of parameters 'a' and 'b' within a multivariate extreme value model

Tags: multivariate-analysis, model, extreme-value, extremal-dependence

It may seems a very silly question for you but it is still quite unclear to me:

What's the meaning of the parameters 'a' and 'b' presented in the Heffernan & Tawn 2004 multivariate model http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2004.02050.x/abstract ?

What they do represent?
Are they the location 'a' and scale 'b' parameters?

thank you very much

Comment: Link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The quantities $\mathbf{a}_{|i}$ and $\mathbf{b}_{|i}$ in the article
both represent a *collection* of $d-1$ functions $a_{j|i}$ and
$b_{j|i}$, for $j \neq i$ in relation with a random vector $\mathbf{Y}
=[Y_i]_i$ with length $d$. The functions $a_{j|i}(y_i)$ and
$b_{j|i}(y_i)$ have as their argument a possible value $y_i$ for the
component $Y_i$. The functions act somewhat as a regression function
and a variance function in a general (non-linear) regression with
response $Y_j$ and regressor $Y_i$, but the regression form holds only
conditional on a large value of the regressor $Y_i$.

As done in some other later articles by the authors and their
co-authors, it helps to consider the case $d=2$ and change the
notations so that the random vector of interest is $[X,\,Y]$.  Then
under ``suitable conditions'' sketched later, the following holds:
Conditional on a large value $x$ of $X$, the distribution of $Y$ tends
to depend on $x$ only through a location parameter $a(x)$ and a scale
parameter $b(x) > 0$. In other words the r.v. $Z := [Y - a(X)] / b(X)$
is independent of $X$ conditional on $X$ when $X$ is large, and
therefore has a distribution $G(z)$ no longer depending on $X$.  To a
certain extend, $Z$ can be compared to the unobservable error term in
a regression-like context, although it does not necessarily have mean
zero and although its distribution is unknown and unspecified.

One possible ``suitable condition'' is that $X$ and $Y$ both have an
exponential tail, or equivalently a Gumbel tail. The magical thing is
that for a large number of dependence models used in practice, only
one special form of functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ exists, depending on a
small number of parameters. For the usual non-negative tail
dependence, a general form is $$ a(x) = \alpha x; \quad b(x) = x^\beta
$$ with $\alpha \leqslant 1$ and $\beta < 1$. In practice we can first transform $X$ and $Y$ so that they have an
exponential tail, using a univariate tail estimation. By using a first
guess for the distribution $G(z)$ e.g. normal, we can find estimates
of the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which control the tail
dependence, and then guess $Z$ and find a non-parametric estimate of
$G(z)$.

Comment: Right. Thank you. So if e.g. I have got a location par 'a' value of 0.9 for a given variable, it means that its correlation with the dependent variable is high?

Comment: With my notations, a high value of $\alpha \approx 1$ means a stronger
dependence of $Y$ on $X$ for large values, which differs from
correlation. The limit case $\alpha = 1$ leads to the *tail
dependence*, an important notion in Extreme Value Theory.

Comment: Thanks! So I assume that the same can be applied to the scale parameter 'b'? e.g. b = 0.9 means a strong variance dependence between Y and X?